# Catch repeats String twice

Tags: java, recursion, while-loop, try-catch

I'm a beginner and I need some help.
I got to do a project in my college. It's a simple game.

In this method I can choose how many rounds I want to play.

```
If number is less than 5 and more than 30 program will say - "You need to choose between 5 and 30!"
If I type letters or words, program will say - "You cannot type letters/words here!" +  "Please, try again. Choose between 5 - 30"
```

I have while and try catch, so if I type a wrong input, program will still run.

So my question is: why does catch repeats twice in my code?

**Console:**

```
How many rounds do you want to play? (5-30)
You cannot type letters/words here!Please, try again. Choose between 5 - 30
How many rounds do you want to play? (5-30)
```

**Code**

```
private void setGameRounds() {

    System.out.println("How many rounds do you want to play? (5-30)");
    while (true) {
        try {
            gameRounds = scan.nextLine();
            int gameRoundsInt = Integer.parseInt(gameRounds);
            if (gameRoundsInt >= 5 && gameRoundsInt <= 30) {
                System.out.println("You will play " + gameRoundsInt + " rounds.");
                break;
            } else {
                System.out.println("You need to choose between 5 and 30!");
                setGameRounds();
                break;
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("You cannot type letters/words here!" +
                    "Please, try again. Choose between 5 - 30");
            setGameRounds();

        }
    }
}
```

[image: img]

Comment: The purpose of a `while(true)` is to automaticlly execute the code again, so don't call `setGameRounds()` inside itself that useless and fails to do what you want

Comment: Instead of just some partial code which we can't compile in order to help you, please paste in a [mre].

Answer (score 0):

Catch block doesn't repeats twice. The method `setGameRounds()` calls itself recursively on some conditions and whenever these conditions are met it will execute the first line of the method again and again. If you want to avoid these then put the line in the original caller method before calling the method `setGameRounds()`